# Phonegap alternative of mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have created an HTML game which is using "mouseover" event of html. All div touches by mouse will turn its color to red.

```
$( ".someDiv" ).on( "mousemove", function() {
    $(this).css("background", "red");
});
```

The problem is, it doesn't work on mobiles. I also use jQuery Mobile's *touchmove*, *vmousemove* and *vmouseover* but they doesn't give me the same result as the *mousemove*. They just detect the touchmove but the same div is touched.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".someDiv").on("mousemove", function() {
        $(this).css("background", "red");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".someDiv").on("touchstart", function() {
    $(this).css({ 'background-color': '#ff0000' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that when using phonegap, you should use "pagecreate" or "pageinit" instead of $(document).ready. like this:

```
$(document).on("pagecreate","#yourpageid",function(){

    $(".myclass").on( "vmouseover", function(){
        // do something you want 
    });               
});
```

> $(document).ready() will/may trigger before your first page is loaded
>   and every code intended for a page manipulation will execute only
>   after a page refresh. This can be a very subtle problem. On some
>   systems, it may appear that it works fine, but on others it may cause
>   strange, difficult to repeat weirdness to occur.

In addition, you might experience different behaviour between your mobile app/browser and desktop web browser. So you have to test the final code in targeted mobile device to see real results.

Additional info and code examples are described here:
[jQuery document ready vs jQuery Mobile page events](http://www.gajotres.net/document-onpageinit-vs-document-ready/)